# NiFi - How to grab specific DOM element based on value on child elements

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, apache-nifi

I am trying to grab an ID based on a certain logic (there can be multiple ID's with same name because its a nifi which uses angular/jquery). Example,

### Logic Below

```
#connection-configuration-tabs-content
    #connection-settings-tab-content
        .settings-left
            .setting(2nd child)
                .setting-field
                    #connection-id (**GRAB**)
    #connection-details-tab-content
            #processor-source-name[title="ARCH_convertCSVToAvro"] (**if exist in this location**)
            #processor-destination-name[title="ARCH_convertAvroToORC"] (**and if exist in this location**)
```

I want to grab "connection-id" based on the locators of #processor-source-name[title="ARCH_convertCSVToAvro"] and #processor-destination-name[title="ARCH_convertAvroToORC"]. The connection-id value varies between diferrent processor-source/destination names but I want to grab that specific one based on the processor-source/destination names.

How do I grab #connection-id in that scenario? Is there a way to do so? I will be grabbing with selenium in Java.

Purpose: I need to uniquely grab the "connnection" id (ex. success/failure queue) in nifi without having unique names based on the previous and forwarding processor names (which are unique in my flow).

Comment: Add html. What you trying to get id or element?

Comment: IMO, instead of providing a dummy manipulated HTML, the raw text based HTML would help the contributors to construct a well researched answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try xpath like below:

```
//*[@id='connection-configuration-tabs-content' and (.//*[@id='processor-source-name' and @title='ARCH_convertCSVToAvro'] or .//*[@id='processor-destination-name' and @title='ARCH_convertAvroToORC'])]//*[@id='connection-id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Selenium's WebDriver API to dynamically select that element based on criteria? You can also make a call to NiFi's REST API to retrieve the connection ID value for various connections on a processor.